# Problem with each in array inputs

Tags: jquery

Hey guys i have this inputs

```
<input name='text[en]' value='aaaaaa' />
<input name='text[fr]' value='bbbb' />
```

I can obtain values with each using `$(this).val()`, but how i can obtain en,es that are inside de name

Answer (score 2):

This will do it

```
var lang = this.name.match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').each(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('name').match(/text\[([a-z]{2})\]/)[1]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.name
```

Will get you the full string like 'text[en]'. Then you can use a regex or substring to find the two letter code you are looking for.

An example would be:

```
var code = this.name.substring(5,6);
```

EDIT: Updated to reflect Gedrox's simplification.

Comment: There is no need to ask jQuery for name. `this.name` will be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input").each(function(){
   var name = $(this).attr("name");
   name = name.substring(name.indexOf("[") + 1, name.indexOf("]") - name.indexOf("]") -1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
      var name = $(this).attr('name');
      var name = name.slice(-3, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to match the name to the regex

```
var match = /(.*)\[([^\]]+)\]/.exec($(this).attr('name'));
```

match[0] will contain the part before the square brackets, match[1] will contain the shorthand language code.